# Can we retrieve submitted data if Save Form Data To Storage is unchecked on a WFFM form?

Tags: wffm

We have `Send Email Message` Save Action attached with WFFM form and `Save Form Data To Storage` field is unchecked.

While submitting the form, mail goes perfectly but data not stored in WFFM SQL DB (I believe it's because of field `Save Form Data To Storage` is unchecked) -We are using `sqlFormsDataProvider`.

My question is can we get the data which was submitted during unchecked stage of field `Save Form Data To Storage`. From anywhere like reporting DB or any specific MongoDB collection ?

Thanks in advance!!
Pushpendra

Answer (score 1):

No, the data is not stored anywhere.

When the `Save Form Data To Storage` is unchecked, this is exactly what happens, the data is not stored and persisted to any database, it is only made available to your Save Actions.

Unless your Save Actions themselves store this data somewhere or make logging calls, the data is not stored by WFFM module.

Comment: Thanks !!Was expecting the same .Just wanted to confirm !!. Just add here this setting required only in CM environment.